# Aplicar dados de um txt para ArrayList

Tags: java, string, arraylist, txt

Preciso de dicas sobre como criar (por onde começar, quais funções usar, etc).

Um projeto genérico que receba um arquivo `.txt`, leia os dados e armazene as palavras em um `ArrayList<>`.

Já criei uma estrutura para:

- Carregar um arquivo `.txt`( dentro do projeto ) através do `input` do
  usuário;
- Ler os dados do arquivo;

Não tenho noção de como pegar as informações deste '.txt' e aplicá-lo no `ArrayList<>`.

**Código :**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner ler = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.printf("Informe o nome de arquivo texto:\n");
    String nome = ler.nextLine();

    System.out.printf("\nConteúdo do arquivo texto:\n");
    try {
      FileReader arq = new FileReader(nome);
      BufferedReader lerArq = new BufferedReader(arq);

      String linha = lerArq.readLine(); // lê a primeira linha

      while (linha != null) {
        System.out.printf("%s\n", linha);

        linha = lerArq.readLine(); // lê da segunda até a última linha
      }

      arq.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.printf("Erro na abertura do arquivo: %s.\n",
          e.getMessage());
    }

    System.out.println();
  }
```

Comment: Você quer salvar cada linha do arquivo em um `ArrayList`?

Comment: Como está a linha desse arquivo? você quer simplesmente jogar a linha completa dentro da posição de um Array? ou quer dividi-la e fazer algum tratamento?

Comment: Então, estou fazendo em partes, primeiro precioso apenas jogar a linha, depois eu começo a fazer o tratamento, usando a vírgula como um separador.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para isto, podemos utilizar o método [split](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-).

Este recebe uma expressão que irá dividir a `String` entre os elementos:

Exemplo:

```
"boo:and:foo".slpit(":");
```

irá resultar em:

```
{ "boo", "and", "foo" }
```

No seu caso, vamos pegar a linhas e separá-las entre os espaços:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner ler = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.printf("Informe o nome de arquivo texto:\n");
    String nome = ler.nextLine();

    System.out.printf("\nConteúdo do arquivo texto:\n");
    try {
        /**
         * VAMOS CRIAR A LISTA DE STRINGS ONDE VAMOS ARMAZENAR
         */
        List<String> listPalavras = new ArrayList<>();

      FileReader arq = new FileReader(nome);
      BufferedReader lerArq = new BufferedReader(arq);

      String linha = lerArq.readLine(); // lê a primeira linha

      while (linha != null) {
        System.out.printf("%s\n", linha);
          /**
           * PARA PEGARMOS AS PALAVRAS,VAMOS SEPARAR A LINHA POR ESPAÇOS!
           */
        String[] palavrasDaLinha = linha.split(" ");
        /**
           * VAMOS ARAMZENAR O ARRAY NA LISTA
           */
        for(String palavra : palavrasDaLinha) {
              /**
               * VAMOS CONSIDERAR PALAVRAS APENAS O QUE TENHA UM TAMANHO MAIOR QUE 1 
               * ESPACOS VAZIOS, TAMBÉM NAO SÃO CONSIDERADOS
               */
            if( palavra.trim().length() > 1 && !"".equals(palavra.trim())) {
                listPalavras.add(palavra);  
            }

        }

        linha = lerArq.readLine(); // lê da segunda até a última linha
      }

      arq.close();
      /**
       * VAMOS INFORMAR O TAMANHO DA LISTA, POR EXEMPLO
       */
      System.out.println("\n\n");
      System.out.printf("Total de palavras no arquivo: %s\n", listPalavras.size());

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.printf("Erro na abertura do arquivo: %s.\n",
          e.getMessage());
    }

    System.out.println();
  }
```